# Clear form fields after submission

Tags: php, forms

this is my first question!

I'm working on a simple email spoofer, but the problem is, when you click the submit button, the form fields save the originally entered values, and that means you can spam someone with tons of the same email easily by either pressing the submit button a lot or refreshing the page.

I would like some assistance.

**Index.php** - http://pastebin.com/dWp5V9vW

**Mail.php** - http://pastebin.com/DdZs8Rhq

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Could you put your code directly in your question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're dropping the submitted field data into the HTML elements using PHP.

Here is the form HTML without the PHP extras.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="from" placeholder="From" value="">
  <input type="text" name="to" placeholder="To" value="">
  <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" value="">
  <textarea name="body"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sent">
</form>
```

Just replace it in your `index.php` file.

**Edit**: If you're feeling a bit lazy, I did it for you: http://pastebin.com/XDZyva5T

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'm new to PHP so I didn't know it was this simple.

Comment: That's ok! The original author of the code you provided doesn't appear to know PHP that well either, hehe :) hope you learn well.